# change the value of a query when inserting

Tags: oracle

tab1

column1 =4
column2 =  (empty column )
column3 =   also empty

what I want is when I insert data into column2

```
  column2 = test
```

I want column 2 to have the data of column1 , I want to have such result

column 2= 4test

I know I can achieve that with a trigger or procedure , I am asking you if there is another way when I insert it

Comment: update tab1 set column2 = column1 || 'test' where condition;

Comment: I want that when I insert the data the value to change .. in triger when you insert a data the trigger will execute and update the value  I want to update the value while inserting ..

Comment: There can be trigger for insert as well. And even with plain insert into, you have all data, you can concatenate it any way. I do not see your poblem.

Comment: the best way to solve your problem is to write a trigger. all the other ways need some additional manual work to do.

Comment: @VikasHardia what kind of manual work ? thats what am searching for

Comment: u have to update the column3 every time like u can see in below answer of leos

Comment: @VikasHardia If I created a trigger , it will be mutating because I am updating on the same table

Comment: @Moundiz If you are version 11g or higher, take a look at [Virtual Columns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF53549).

Comment: create a view and insert values on that view and dont include the column 3 in view and create insert trigger on that view and use instead  of insert on to table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
update tab1 set column2 = column1 || 'test' where condition;
```